# Youtube playlist downloader using Javascript

Tags: javascript

i am creating a youtube playlist downloader using youtube-dl-exec but it seem not working, can anyone help me to fix this code
Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>YouTube Video Downloader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>YouTube Video Downloader</h1>
    <form id="downloadForm" action="/download" method="post">
      <label for="videoUrl">YouTube Video URL:</label>
      <input type="text" id="videoUrl" name="videoUrl" required />
      <button type="submit">Download</button>
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>
    <script src="server.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const youtubedl = require("youtube-dl-exec");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
  const videoUrl = req.body.videoUrl;
  const videosDir = "./videos"; // Define your video directory
  const outputDir = "./divided_videos"; // Define your output directory
  const numVideosPerFile = 100; // Define the number of videos per file

  // Function to download YouTube video
  const downloadYouTubeVideo = async () => {
    const options = {
      cwd: videosDir,
      format: "best",
      dump_json: true,
    };

    try {
      const info = await youtubedl(videoUrl, options);
      const outputFilePath = `${videosDir}/${info.title}.${info.ext}`;
      const downloadOptions = { cwd: videosDir };
      await youtubedl.raw(info.url, downloadOptions);
      return info.title;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error downloading video:", error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  // Execute the download function
  const videoTitle = await downloadYouTubeVideo();

  if (videoTitle) {
    // Divide the videos into files
    divideVideosIntoFiles(videosDir, outputDir, numVideosPerFile);
    res.send(`Video "${videoTitle}" downloaded and divided.`);
  } else {
    res.send("Error downloading video.");
  }
});

function divideVideosIntoFiles(videosDir, outputDir, numVideosPerFile) {
  const videoFiles = fs.readdirSync(videosDir);
  let fileNum = 1;
  let currentFile = `${outputDir}/file_${fileNum}.mp4`;
  let outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(currentFile);

  for (let i = 0; i < videoFiles.length; i++) {
    const videoPath = `${videosDir}/${videoFiles[i]}`;
    const videoData = fs.readFileSync(videoPath);
    outputStream.write(videoData);

    if ((i + 1) % numVideosPerFile === 0) {
      outputStream.end();
      fileNum++;
      currentFile = `${outputDir}/file_${fileNum}.mp4`;
      outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(currentFile);
    }
  }

  outputStream.end();
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

i want to download a playlist from youtube and save into files, each file contains 100 videos so if the playlist have 325 videos then videos will be divide into 4 files (first 3 files will have 100 videos and last on will have 25 videos)
i have already write code in Javascript

Comment: You need to be more descriptive rather than saying "it seems to be not working...any console errors you've identified?

Comment: There is a very obvious issue here...

Answer (score 0):

Your server.js is a node.js file, a backend program. It cannot be run in the frontend. You are currently doing that, by `<script src="server.js"></script>` in the HTML.

You want to run server.js on a server. Instead of having a static page, I would suggest just making it a express app altogether, by adding the HTML into the node:

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>YouTube Video Downloader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>YouTube Video Downloader</h1>
    <form id="downloadForm" action="/download" method="post">
      <label for="videoUrl">YouTube Video URL:</label>
      <input type="text" id="videoUrl" name="videoUrl" required />
      <button type="submit">Download</button>
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>

  </body>
</html>`)
})
```

in server.js, and running server.js on a server, or on your computer.